# Laravel запрос на вывод групп

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Как мне вывести по группам для определенного teacher

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<optgroup label="Дата">
    <option>Время</option>
    <option>Время</option>
    <option>Время</option>
    <option>Время</option>
    <option>Время</option>
    <option>Время</option>
  </optgroup>


$time = DB::table('demos')
            ->leftJoin('relations', 'demos.teacher', '=', 'relations.teacher')
            ->select('demos.ddate as ddate', 'demos.dtaime','demos.status', 'demos.id')
            ->where('relations.id', $request->relation)->orderBy('demos.ddate', 'asc')->get();
```

Comment: каких групп, как вывести, в виде чего и т.п. Дополните вопрос

Comment: чтобы была дата, а внизу время этой даты